# Unable to load Shapefile using pgShapeloader / shp2pgsql-gui (pgAdmin3's PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Tool)

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, osm2pgsql, pgadmin-3

I am trying to load a shapefile (http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/nationalatlas/statesp020_nt00032.tar.gz) into PostGIS 2.0.1 using pgAdmin3's PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Tool.

[image]

However its not allowing me to import the shapefile, showing the error messages below. Any idea what happen?

**Output from PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Tool**

```
==============================
Importing with configuration: statesp020, staging, geom, C:\gisdata\statesp020_nt00032\statesp020, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=0, shape=1, srid=4269
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Failed SQL begins: "SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS TO ON;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "staging"."statesp020" (gid serial,
"area" float8,
"perimeter" float8,
"statesp020" float8,
"state" varchar(20),
"state_fips" varchar(2),
"order_adm" int4,
"month_adm""
Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 15: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('staging','statesp020','geom','4269...
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Shapefile import failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the loader you're using is from 1.5 or lower, while the database you're loading to is 2.0. Either (a) move to the latest loader or (b) add the "legacy.sql" file into your postgis database to ensure that all the old function signatures the old loader expects are available to you.

Comment: I cant seem to find the newest `shp2pgsql-gui.exe` loader for Windows, im using the latest version that I can find. Any hints on where to get the updated version?

Comment: Particularly on Windows I'd expect it to be bundled with the latest PostGIS software... afraid I can't help you.